# Creating and adding a file to a solution via add-in

Tags: c#, file, visual-studio-2012, solution, visual-studio-addins

Hi everyone I wanted to know if I can create an add-in where it creates a file and adds it to the solution? If it's possible how can I do it?

This is the use case -

> When a aspx extension file is open and I click on my add-in, it will
>   check the file for "meta:resourcekey" and then create a resource file
>   in the solution and add all the resource keys in it. I just don't know
>   how to create and add a file to the visual studio 2012 solution with
>   an add-in. What kind of a code do I write to create a file and add it
>   to the solution

Would really appreciate some tips.
I am using VS2012

Comment: Would you mind adding more details? Add-in for what?

Comment: An add-in for VS2012.

Comment: what kind of file, what solution? what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: Okay so my add-in will work like this: When a aspx extension file is open and I click on my add-in, it will check the file for "meta:resourcekey" and then create a resource file in the solution and add all the resource keys in it. I just don't know how to create and add a file to the visual studio 2012 solution with an add-in. What kind of a code do I write to create a file and add it to the solution ?